# w2ui remote source enum field in a Form

Tags: w2ui

I have an enum field linked to a remote source and as you type in the field the remote source supplies matches, which pop up just like you would expect. It works great. But I need that field to be in a Form. The problem is that when it's in the form it no longer works. I stripped the code down and listed it below. Hopefully the code below is enough, but you can click the links provided to try it and view source for the next couple of weeks or so.

Can anyone explain how to make it work in the Form?

This code works ([try it here](http://ec2-54-86-115-252.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8270/html/test/enumtest.html)):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Remote Source Enum</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="w2ui-field"><label>Name Picker:</label><div> <input id="tcidPicker"></div></div>
<script>
$('#tcidPicker').w2field('enum', {
    url: '/v1/transactantstd/ISO',
    renderItem: function (item) {return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName; },
    renderDrop: function (item) {return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName; },
    compare: function (item, search) {
        // ... lines removed for brevity ...
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code does not work ([try it here](http://ec2-54-86-115-252.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8270/html/test/picktest.html)):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Remote Source Enum in a Form</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rawgit.com/vitmalina/w2ui/master/dist/w2ui.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="form">
    <div class="w2ui-field">
    <label>Name Picker:</label><input id="tcidPicker" name="tcidPicker">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#form').w2form({ 
        name  : 'form',
        fields: [
            { field: 'tcidPicker', 
                type: 'enum', 
                url: '/v1/transactantstd/ISO',
                renderItem: function (item) {return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName; },
                renderDrop: function (item) {return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName; },
                compare: function (item, search) {
                    // ... lines removed for brevity
                },
            },
        ],
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the options in a `options` property.

See: http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2form.fields

In your case:

```
    fields: [
        { field: 'tcidPicker', 
            type: 'enum', 
            options: {
                url: '/v1/transactantstd/ISO',
                renderItem: function (item) {return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName; },
                renderDrop: function (item) {return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName; },
                compare: function (item, search) {
                    // ... lines removed for brevity
                },
            },
        },
    ],
```

Comment: Just made this change.  Works like a champ now.  Thanks mpf82!